# Difference between coinbase and blockchain displayed transaction/network costs

Tags: transactions, ethereum

I from time to time send ETH from Coinbase to another adress. I check the transaction on etherscan.io. There is the "Value" displayed and the "Transaction Fee":

[image: ex1]

However, Coinbase also displays a "network fee" and this differs:

[image: ex2]

The total amount of ETH which was substracted from my Coinbase account is the "Value" plus the network fee. Now it turns out the network fee which Coinbase displays and charges is lower than the displayed transaction fee on etherscan. Why is there this kind of difference? And why wasn't Value + Transaction Fee substracted from my Coinbase account? So the network fee coinbase displays and charged me on the transaction is lower than the one displayed at etherscan. I do not understand this.